# Updating view position after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm working on getting a animation to work. I'm moving a search bar from the middle of the screen to the top of the screen. The animation works fine, but once it's moved I can't interact with anything. I've updated the position but can't interact with it regardless. Here's what I've got so far:

```
private void moveSearchToTop()
{
    FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.rootLayout );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    mSearchBar.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    search_top = statusBarOffset - originalPos[1];
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, 0, search_top);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mSearchBar.layout(0, search_top, 0, mSearchBar.getHeight() + search_top);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    mSearchBar.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

and here's what the view looks like in xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSearchClick"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/search"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Search"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Do I need to update the position of all of the child elements too? Thanks for a push in the right position.

Comment: You're using a view animation which is only going to change where it is drawn, not the actual position. I'm sure there are ways to trick it into moving the actual position, but I always find it is just easier to use an object animator to begin with as it will update the actual position without me having to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't need to modify the child views. They will go where the search bar goes.

It looks to me like you are using your search_top variable both as a delta (for the TranslateAnimation constructor) and as a position within its parent (in the call to layout). It's really a delta, so the call to layout is incorrect.

Is the parent of your searchBar the "root" FrameLayout? If so, then you just want to use 0 as the new y coordinate in the call to layout. Also, you are using 0 as the right coordinate, which means that it has no width after the animation. This call would position your search bar at the upper-left edge of its parent, and maintain its current width and height:

```
 mSearchBar.layout(0, 0, mSearchBar.getWidth(), mSearchBar.getHeight());
```

I also would recommend that you do not use screen position. It's safer to just set the position of views within parent views. For example, if the search bar's parent really is root, then you could get the delta with:

```
search_top = - mSearchBar.getTop();
```